# add button is sticky

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying a todo list website from theodinproject.com, but i got stuck when am trying to add multiple lists my add buttons just overlaps the list even though i applied `display: flex;` to it

here is my html

```
    <section id="todo-left">
          <ul>
            <li>Default</li>
            <li>Web Development</li>
            <li>Default</li>
            <li>Web Development</li>
          </ul>
          <button>Add</button>
        </section>
```

and here is my scss

```
    #todo-left{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-grow: inherit;
      padding: 20px;
      background: lightgray;
      @include size(100%, 200px);
    }
```

here size is a mixin with properties `height` & `width`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I61fn.jpg)
here is the snap shot of problem

Comment: Glad you were able to solve you own issue!  I would recommend posting your solution as an actual answer to your question ([self-answering is allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)).  That way it is more visible to help others, and you may gain some reputation from upvotes if visitors find it helpful.  Happy coding!

Comment: @AlexanderNied oh i am new to stack overflow so i dont have idea before thanks for this tip:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i try a lot of this to this problem, at the end i just realize in spite of setting hard code height we can fix this using `height: auto;` and it worked, may this post help you guys!